# double insert with relation

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-insert-id

I have two tables.

```
Table1 is named "titles" and has 3 columns: id, pagetitle, pages_id
Table2 is named "pages" and has 2 columns: id, content
```

In a form I am submitting 2 form fields: `title, content`

Now, I want to insert each value in each table, but of course I want to make sure that `titles.pages_id` is the same value as `pages.id`. Both `titles.id` and `pages.id` are auto-increment.

**This is not a PHP question**

I know how to do this using PHP by making two separate sql statements and using `mysqli_insert_id()` from the first query in the second one.

But I think there is a SQL-only way of doing a multi-insert query... or is there?

Comment: maybe try MySQl stored procedures? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/stored-routines.html

Comment: If you want to insert into two tables, you need two queries.

Comment: @Dan - perhaps i'm not using correct nomenclature, but I thought with `transactions` I can do multiple `INSERT` in a single statement, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The auto increment won't stop you from inserting a specific id. just insert into one table first and use that id when inserting into the 2nd table.

Comment: well, but the whole point of the auto_increment for me is so I don't ever have to think about posible duplicates, the database will ensure the id is unique. I guess I forgot to say I also use `unique` attribute on the `id` column.

Comment: do you not want the data in the 1st table if it isn't unique in the 2nd. start a `transaction`. if the 2nd `INSERT` fails the unique constraint, `rollback`. if it is ok `commit`. you can't add to 2 tables with 1 statement. but you can run several queries in a transaction and commit them at one time.

Answer (score 0):

After some more experimenting I came up with this statement

```
INSERT INTO pages (`content`) VALUES('hello world'); 
INSERT INTO titles (`pagetitle`, `pages_id`) VALUES ('hw page', LAST_INSERT_ID());
```

Looks like there is no problem doing things this way. it seems to work fine.